# How to prove the inequalities of q-ary lattice determinant?

Tags: lattice-crypto

for $A\in{Z_q^{n*m}}$ and $A^{'}\in{Z_q^{m*n}}$,we have

- $det{({\land}_q^{\bot}(A))}{\le}q^n$ and
  $det{({\land}_q(A^{'}))}{\ge}q^{m-n}$
- if q is prime,and A,A' are    non-singular in the finite field
  $Z_q$,the above inequality are    equalities.

where
${\land}_q^{\bot}(A) = \{x{\in}Z^m|Ax=0{\bmod}q\}$ and ${\land}_q(A)=\{y{\in}Z^m|y=As{\bmod}q\}$

The above content comes from D. Dadush's lecture note(lemma 4) [lecture_9](https://homepages.cwi.nl/%7Edadush/teaching/lattices-2018/notes/lecture-9.pdf).I don't know how to prove the above lemma because the proof in the lecture note is too sketchy for me.I would appreciate it if someone could provide more detailed proof。

Comment: Maybe it is a good place to acknowledge that there are several mistakes in those lecture notes. We are currently working on fixing them :/

Comment: For that particular instance, no mistakes, but maybe an explicit invocation of Lemma 10 of Lecture 2 would help 
https://homepages.cwi.nl/~dadush/teaching/lattices-2018/notes/lecture-2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I get inspiration from vadim's ppt.But I only prove half of the theorem.

**Proof**:
${\because}{\land_q^{\bot}}(A)$ is a integer lattice, ${\therefore}
{det({\land_q^{\bot}}(A))}=|{Z^m}/{\land_q^{\bot}}(A)|$.
let us define a mapping ${f}:{Z^m}{\to}{Z_q^{n}}$,${f:Ax{\bmod}q}$.It's easy to verify that $f$ is homomorphic.According to the basic theorem of homomorphism，$|{Z^m}/kerf|=|{Z^m}/{\land_q^{\bot}}(A)|=|im({Z^m})|$.Because $im({Z^m}){\subseteq}{Z_q^{n}}$,so ${det({\land_q^{\bot}}(A))}=|{Z^m}/{\land_q^{\bot}}(A)|{\leq}q^n$.
If q is prime,and A is non-singular,then $f$ is full homomorphism because every image in ${Z_q^{n}}$ can find the original image in ${Z^m}$.So $im({Z^m})={Z_q^{m}}$ and ${det({\land_q^{\bot}}(A))}=|{Z^m}/{\land_q^{\bot}}(A)|=q^n$.

However,I haven't found a way to prove the other half of the theorem. I would be grateful if someone could give the rest of the proof.

Comment: Could you give a source about the definition of a determinant?

Comment: The second half of the theorem follows from basic lattice facts. For any lattice $\Lambda$, we have that $\det \Lambda \det \Lambda^* = 1$, where $\Lambda^*$ is the dual lattice. $\Lambda_q^\perp(A)$ and $\Lambda_q(A)$ are not dual, but they are scaled duals --- in particular $\Lambda_q(A)^* = (1/q)\Lambda_q^\perp(A)$ (and $\Lambda_q^\perp(A)^* = (1/q)\Lambda_q(A)$ ). It follows that $\det \Lambda_q^\perp(A) \det (1/q)\Lambda_q(A) = 1$,  and therefore $1/\det((1/q)\Lambda_q(A)) \leq q^n$. The result then follows from simplifying.

Comment: @Mark，Thank you for your supplement. I know how to prove it.

Comment: @levgeni: I think there's something you want in this [lecture note](https://homepages.cwi.nl/~dadush/teaching/lattices-2018/notes/lecture-2.pdf)